# Wordpress pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress page that shows the latest news. I want to paginate these news, and this is my code:

```
 <?php
query_posts('posts_per_page=5');
?>
<?php
while (have_posts()):
    the_post();
?>
   <div class="news"><h1><a href="<?php
    the_permalink();
?>" rel="news" title="<?php
    the_title_attribute();
?>"><?php
    the_title();
?></a></h1>
    <p>
    <?php
    the_excerpt();
?>
   </p>
    </div>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
<p><?php
wp_pagenavi();
?></p>
<?php
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

I have this code in a page content, i'm using exec-php plugin to parse the code. The problem is that when I click on page 2 I still see the news of the page 1. So pagination isn't working.

Any idea?

On my archive (archive.php) page i've tried the pagination too, but there when I click on page 2 I'm redirected on the homepage instead.

Help me please!

Answer (score 2):

try to use wordpress plugin which will help you for pagination , no need of builtin pagination that was 1 2 3 so on. this plugin gives you better format for pagination.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-post-splitter/

Usage of this Plugin:
https://progtec.wordpress.com/2015/10/13/jquery-post-splitter-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Wordpress reject any URL query parameters that it doesn’t recognise.

Even if you solved that problem, this function

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=5'); ?>
```

does not accept the page parameter so it seems "obvious" showing always page 1. I don't know the code inside it so I could be wrong.

I've found this link to solve the first problem: http://www.webopius.com/content/137/using-custom-url-parameters-in-wordpress

Comment: I assume query_posts() takes the parameters and automatically adjust the query based on 'current_page' parameter. I don't know the code inside too. :o

Answer (score 0):

it might helps you

http://tareq.wedevs.com/2011/07/simple-pagination-system-in-your-wordpress-plugins/

or see below
Easy Steps :

```
$pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
```

Find total numbers of records

```
$limit = 10; // number of rows in page
$offset = ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $limit;
$total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_name" );
$num_of_pages = ceil( $total / $limit );
```

Give limit:

```
$entries = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_name LIMIT $offset, $limit" );
```

Add this code where you want pagination:

```
$page_links = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __( '&laquo;', 'aag' ),
    'next_text' => __( '&raquo;', 'aag' ),
    'total' => $total,
    'current' => $pagenum
) );

if ( $page_links ) {
    echo '<div class="tablenav"><div class="tablenav-pages" style="margin: 1em 0">' . $page_links . '</div></div>';
}
```